# sympy error - AttributeError: sqrt

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python, and I keep getting the following error

```
..., line 27, in <module>
    eq=(p**2+2)/p/sqrt(p**2+4)
AttributeError: sqrt
```

I tried to add `math.sqrt` or `numpy.sqrt` but neither of these work. Does anyone know where I'm going wrong?

My code is:

```
from numpy import *
from matplotlib import *
from pylab import *
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.solvers import solve
p=Symbol('p')
eq=(p**2+2)/p/sqrt(p**2+4)
solve(eq,1.34,set=True)
```

Comment: i dint see your using math.sqrt in your error .please try that import math then use math.sqrt()

Answer (score 1):

sqrt is defined in the math module, import it this way. This should remove the errors!

```
from math import sqrt
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a sympy symbol: either you wanted to do numerical sqrt (in which case use numpy.sqrt on an actual number) or you wanted symbolic sqrt (in which case use sympy.sqrt). Each of the imports replaces the definition of sqrt in the current namespace, from math, sympy or numpy. It's best to be explicit and not use "import *".

I suspect from the line which follows, you want sympy.sqrt here.