# Sympy sqrt function "contains an element of the set of generators"

Tags: python, numpy, sympy, symbolic-math

I've been trying to use sympy's solvers.solve_poly_system but when I go to solve an equation with a sqrt function, I get the following error:

`sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialError: sqrt(x1) contains an element of the set of generators.`

Here is the code in question:

```
# An array of variables is declared as symbols in sympy. This has already worked to solve equations/derivatives.

for x in range(len(coordArr)):
    coordArr[x][0] = symbols(xCoords[x], real = True)
    coordArr[x][1] = symbols(yCoords[x], real = True)

# Then a specific system of equations using the variables in the array is fed into the system solver.

print(sympy.solvers.solve_poly_system([(5*(sympy.sqrt(coordArr[0][0])*2 + 2 - 3)), (2*(coordArr[0][1] - 3))], coordArr[0][0],coordArr[0][1]))
```

After this point, I receive the error. I found some [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24828988/sympy-error-attributeerror-sqrt) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660851/sympy-error-when-using-poly-with-sqrt) posts which seem to be solved by using sympy.sqrt, but I did the same and continued to receive the same error. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You will see this error when the generator you are using does not appear as an integer power in an expression:

```
>>> Poly(sqrt(x) + x, x)
...
sympy.polys.polyerrors.PolynomialError: sqrt(x) contains an element of the set of generators.
```

If you supply no generator Poly will create a polynomial with two generators: `x` and `sqrt(x)`. My suggestion is to use `solve` or `nonlinsolve` for your system of equations.

```
>>> solve((5*(sqrt(x)*2 + 2 - 3), 2*(y - 3)), (x, y))
{x: 1/4, y: 3}
>>> nonlinsolve((5*(sqrt(x)*2 + 2 - 3), 2*(y - 3)), (x, y))
FiniteSet((1/4, 3))
```